# Cross-validation: set aside the validation set based on items or participants?

Tags: correlation, cross-validation

Here is the structure of my data set: group A and B rated 256 items (each group used a different dependent measure) and I found a significant correlation between their ratings.

Now I want to do a cross-validation on this data set but am not sure whether I should **set aside some items** (e.g., 30%) or **some participants** from each group for validation.

Which is the right practice, or does it depend on my purpose? Thanks!

---

Edit:

Two groups of people saw 256 binary sequences (e.g., HHTTHTHT). Group A (40 people) classified each sequence into random/nonrandom while group B (40 people) classified each as "generated by a human/natural phenomenon". So, each sequence has a "nonrandom score" (the proportion of people classified it as "nonrandom") and an "agent score" (the proportion of people classified it as "generated by a human).

Looking at the 256 sequences, I found a strong correlation between the two scores. In order to test how robust the correlation is, should I build a model `lm(agent~nonrandom, data=myData)`based on, say, 180 randomly selected sequences and test how well it works on the rest of the 76 sequence? Alternatively, should I build `lm(agent~nonrandom, data=myData)` based on 28 people in group A and 28 people in group B and see how it extends to the rest of 12 people in each group?  Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide more details.  It also seems like it might be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Hi! I added the details just now and wish to know how you think. Thank you! @MichaelChernick